# how to return Stripe's createToken tokenId and use it in another function in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, stripe-payments, vuex

so I call `Stripe.card.createToken` in my `api.js` file and want to return the token this function generates so I can use it in my vuex, how can I do that?

// api.js

```
export const stripeToken = async ({ cardInfo }) => {
  const { data } = await Stripe.card.createToken({
    cardInfo,
  });
  return data;
};
```

So I want to use it in my actions in vuex like this. I did this and it doesn't work, it returns undefined:

//vuex

```
import { stripeToken } from '@src/store/api';
async stripeToken({ dispatch }, { cardInfo }) {
  const { data } = await stripeToken({ cardInfo });
  console.log('tokenId: ', data.tokenId);
},
```

Comment: How is your import statement looks like in vuex file?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM updated the post with my import

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What exactly is undefined? How is the code used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with vuex, but the `Stripe.card.createToken` method takes two parameters: a JavaScript object containing credit card data entered by the user, and a callback function to handle the response. You can learn more about it in the [Stripe documentation here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2#collecting-card-details).

Here's how you could display the ID of a token with `Stripe.card.createToken`:

```
Stripe.card.createToken(cardInfo, (status, response) => {
  if (response.error) {
    console.log(response.error);
  } else {
    console.log(response.id);
  }
});
```

Note that `Stripe.card.createToken` is an old method from Stripe.js v2 that is now deprecated, so I would recommend [upgrading to Stripe.js v3](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/migrating) if possible.